# network path for direcotries and files longer than 260 character, : system.io.__error.winioerror(int32 errorcode string maybefullpath,

Tags: file, directory, path

I enabled reg key for longPpathEnabled = 1 and restarted the desktop where I am running c# code, but still getting same error, If I tried to pass \?\ along with network path, it thows error as it looks like C# code is not able to recognize the network path as \?\\netowrkshare\Dir\Dir\Sir.... etc.
I looked up Microsoft articles, they mentioned that .net framework 4.6.2 and later have support for path beyond 260 characters, but it does not seems to be working for me. I have visual strdio 2022 with .net framework 4.8 set as target platform.

following path I am trying to query, just as a sample which has more directories and files in it

```
string @fpath = "\\child.main.net\netFS\isFS\department analytic\EDA\Audit_Files\HRFils2\IMPORTANT_DOC\HC_PowerShell\grafana-enterprise-10.1.1.windows-amd64\grafana-10.1.1\docs\sources\administration\roles-and-permissions\access-control"

foreach (string sFileName in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Path.Combine(@fpath.ToString()), fext.ToString(), SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
        //Get file information here
        FileInfo f = new FileInfo(sFileName);

        working code here......
        export these directories and files to excel file

}
```

Can some one please help ? most article seems to be quite old and may be .net framework 4.8 was not available then ?

export all directories and file listing to excel file for audi